# Parse existing log file to a json array : Java

Tags: java, json, string, log4j

I have some log files that returned from **slf4j.Logger**. logs file are in general format like :

```
date<space>time<space>mode<space>logger name<space> - log message
```

log message can have dates, times, space character & even multiple line breaks.

Looking for a way to parse this log file into a **JSON array** like :

```
[{
    "date" : "",
    "time" : "",
    "mode" : "",
    "loggerName": "",
    "message":""
},{next line..},...]
```

I cannot change logger formatter settings hence these are already generated files. Can someone help me to find a way to achieve this goal?

I tried String splits but does not work due to the contend of log messages(they have spaces, line breaks, dates, times).

Require a proper way to get actual log lines without getting into trap of log message contents.

Comment: You can get the first 4 fields by the delimiting spaces -- then everything left after `<space><space>-<space>` is the log message. Where exactly are you having a problem?

Comment: log message can have line breaks, spaces and dates. Require a proper way to get actual log lines without getting into trap of log message contents.

Comment: how to find whether it is an actual beginning of a log line?

Comment: cannot assume that log message content has not sequences like <line-break><number><space>

Comment: After you have found a log line, (one starting with the expected pattern), assume the following lines are part of the log message unless they start with the expected pattern. Express the pattern in more detail (i.e. recognise a date, time and mode as more than just strings) to get more accuracy.

Comment: I think it is possible. Is there any library or tool to do log parsing in an accurate way?

Comment: Create a regular expression which matches the start of a log line with as little uncertainty as possible. As you haven't shown your log messages, we can't help you with that, but there are plenty of good regex tutorials.

Comment: If i was in this situation, I would try to find the regex which can help me identify the start of the line. Any line which matches regex like date<space>time<space>mode<space>logger_ name

date and time would follow same format. Mode can be some finite number of values and loggere_name will also be some finite number of unique values. Once you know start of line, rest is to play with space and split the string

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this [thekrakken/java-grok](https://github.com/thekrakken/java-grok)

> Simple API that allows you to easily parse logs and other files

it is inspired by logstash filter [Grok filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_description_135)